# Measuring Always On Availability Group potential data loss

Tags: sql-server, replication, availability-groups

I have read these articles few times. I do monitor potential data loss today using some of the methods described in these articles.

1. [Measuring Availability Group synchronization lag](https://www.sqlshack.com/measuring-availability-group-synchronization-lag/) by Derik Hammer
2. [Monitor Performance for AlwaysOn Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/dn135338(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
3. [Monitoring Availability Group Replica Synchronization](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/08/monitoring/availability-group-replica-sync) by Jonathan Kehayias

Reading these articles and the description of dynamic management views and performance counters, I do not see any way to measure the exact time for potential data loss if Primary goes down now.

I did inquire about using log sequence number (LSN) values from `sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states`. Found out only certain LSN's has a timestamp. Plus, continuously querying the timestamp of those particular LSN is probably not a practical solution.

Do you know how to get the exact time for potential data loss at any given time?

A hypothetical solution will be finding the oldest LSN's timestamp that has not been copied to the secondary.

Answer (score 1):

I've occassionally created specific tables for this purpose, sometimes called "tracer" or "canary" tables. It has one column which is a datetime. A job runs on the source system inserting the current time. This runs at whatever granularity you need - minutes apart was sufficient for me. Read the max value from the secondary & that's how far behind you are.

Comment: Thank you. I have done that too and blogged about it. That included 'log copy'+'log replay'. I am not concerned about log replay because that is not going to cause me data loss. I want to exactly measure how far behind I am on the copy.